# How to create new tabs in new window using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having list of contacts as link in my `current web page`.
So When I click any contact first time, then that link should open in new window, After that when ever I'm click the contact, those links should open as a `tab` in the `newly created window`, Not in current window.
So How could I do it.
For open a new window, I am using,

```
var myWindow = window.open("", "MsgWindow", "width=200,height=100");
myWindow.document.write("<p>This is 'MsgWindow'. I am 200px wide and 100px tall!</p>");
```

For open a new tab, I'm using,

```
var url = "http://www.example.com";
 window.open(url, '_blank');
```

Please Help me, Thanks.

Comment: I think this question is answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907843/open-a-url-in-a-new-tab-and-not-a-new-window-using-javascript